# There exists a nonzero vector $v$ such that $S(v)$ is a multiple of $T(v)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following proposition -

> Let $T$ and $S$ be operators on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Then, there exists a nonzero vector $v\in V$ such that $S(v)$ is a multiple of $T(v)$.

My attempt -

Suppose for all nonzero vector $v\in V$, $S(v) \neq \lambda T(v)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Then, for all $v \neq 0$, $(S-\lambda T)(v) \neq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. This means $S-\lambda T$ is injective for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. This cannot be true since setting $\lambda = 0$ would inply that every operator $S$ on $V$ is injective.

Can anyone think of other proofs?

Comment: You should probably be a bit more careful about quantifiers! It is true that $S-\lambda T$ ranges through all possible operators in $V$ when $S,T$ and $\lambda$ are free, and in particular that it hits non-injective operators, but what you want to show is that for fixed $S$ and $T$, the line (affine subspace) $S-\lambda T$ hits a non-injective operator as $\lambda$ ranges through scalars in $\mathbb C$. This is different!

Comment: For comparison, consider your idea when $T$ is the identity of $V$, where you want to show that any operator $S$ admits an eigenvector. Then crucially you need to use that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, which you have not used in your proof.

Comment: @Pedro I see my error now. Is it possible to show that $S-\lambda T$ can be non-injective for a certain choice of $\lambda$? Or is this approach wrong to prove the proposition?

Comment: As illustrated in an answer below, the statement is false in general. It is true if and only if $S$ is singular or $S^{-1}T$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: I think you wanted to show that $S(v)$ and $T(v)$ are linearly dependent.  This splits to two cases $\det S = 0$, in which case select non-zero $v\in \ker S$.  Otherwise you want non-zero $v$ satisfying $\mathbf 0=(\lambda S -T)v= S(\lambda I -S^{-1}T)v$  and of course $(S^{-1}T)$ has at least one satisfying eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Let $T=0$ and $S=I$ (the identity operator). If $v \neq 0$ then $Sv=v$ so $Sv$ cannot be a multiple of $0=Tv$

Comment: I am giving a counter-example. I Take $S$ to be the identity operator, so $Sv$ is same as $v$. @kmiyazaki